# NullPointerException, setting adapter on null object

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get a Staggered Grid layout using a `RecyclerView` in one of my ViewPagers fragments. When I start the app, it immediately crashes and throws this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)'
>   on a null object reference
>               at xxx.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:39)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)

My first thought is that this might be caused by the order in which the views are loaded but i'm not sure. I have a `ViewPager` with 2 fragments. I have the `RecyclerView` declared in the first fragments xml, like so:

res/layout/fragment_home.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/home_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Heres the relative parts of my Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setupToolbar();
    setupTabs();

    HomeGridAdapter adapter = new HomeGridAdapter(Contacts.createFakeContacts(20));

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.home_grid);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));


}
```

Here is the first fragments Java file:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

private int mPage;

public static HomeFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}


}
```

I dont think i need to post the RecyclerViews adapter code as I dont think that is part of the issue, but if its needed I can.

Any input on this issue is appreciated!

**EDIT:** As requested, heres my activitys xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating your ViewPager? Can you post your Activity layout xml? It seems your Activity doesn't have the ViewPager loaded on it, so the RecyclerView which is in the ViewPager will not exist on onCreate() resulting in null.

Comment: Added my activities xml file. The viewpager is binded with butterknife up higher, and the `setupTabs()` method sets up the TabLayout and ViewPager. I didnt include it as i didnt think its part of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading activity_home in activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

and your home_grid is located in first_fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/home_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your getting at here.

Comment: You mentioned wrong xml in activity

Comment: Did you try creating the recyclerview in fragment. Try moving the recyclerview code into fragment from activity.

Comment: @Nilesh How is it the wrong activity, re-read the question please. Ravi I tried initiating the recyclerview in both my fragments onCreate and onCreateView methods and got the same error.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_home); in you code which does not contain RecyclerView

Comment: @Nilesh Please leave this question, you have obviously not read or do not understand it. I am completely aware that it does not contain RecyclerView. The RecyclerView is inside one of the fragments in a viewpager.

Answer (score 1):

Within `onCreate()` of your Activity, first find your `ViewPager`:

```
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    MyFragmentPagerAdaptor adaptor = new
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adaptor);
```

Within the Activity Class, Create a new `FragmentPagerAdapter` nested class called `MyFragmentPagerAdapter`, which returns your Fragment on the `getItem()` method.

Currently, your ViewPager doesn't have any content inside and you are not loading the fragment into the `ViewPager`. (Purely from the code I see. I may be wrong)

Now that your `ViewPager` has the fragment content inside, you need a way to access the child View within the fragment (within the `Viewpager`).

This will not be directly possible, so you need to create a instance of the fragment you are looking for using your adaptor's `getItem()` method:

```
Fragment f = (Fragment) adaptor.getItem(pager.getCurrentItem());
```

Although `getCurrentItem()` can be replaced with an index pointing directly to your Fragment, which should have already been defined within the `getItem()`.

Finally, You can find your child view within the fragment like so:

```
RecyclerView theViewINeed = (RecyclerView)f.getView().findViewById(R.id.home_grid);
```

---

edit: seems like the Fragment's `OnCreateView()` is not called during the parent Activity's `OnCreate()`.

Try moving the below code to `OnStart`. (Put the Fragment reference you obtain from `onCreate()` as a field, and access it during `onStart()`)

```
RecyclerView theViewINeed = (RecyclerView)f.getView().findViewById(R.id.home_grid);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not concerned with setting up the ViewPager, as I said in my comment to you im already doing that in a helper method-`setupTabs()`. The Tabs and ViewPager work fine. Anyway, I tried getting the fragment directly using this: `HomeFragment f = (HomeFragment) pagerAdapter.getItem(0);` and then calling f.getView...... but It still threw the same error.

Comment: That would mean that getItem(0) is returning null. Maybe you can post the code for the adaptor? I still think that although your getItem() is returning an improper fragment, maybe the fragment itself is not being initialized with your xml layout. Also please post the fragment constructor if possible.

Comment: Hmm I dont think so. Again my viewPager works flawlessly. I just added a quick if/else log statement and checked `if (pagerAdapter.getItem(0) != null)` and it said it wasn't null so.. I dont think this is an issue with the adapter. I added a log statement right after instantiating the recyclerView to check if its null, and it is. So the problem is this line in my Activity `RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.home_grid);` is coming up with `recyclerView` being null, for whatever reason. Any ideas why?

Comment: Hmm I think the fragment's OnCreateView() is not called during the Activity's OnCreate(). Try to move the getView().findViewById() code to the onStart of your Activity. I have put an edit to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You have specified **activity_home.xml** layout for `Activity`

while your `RecyclerView` tag is in **fragment_home.xml**

try to initialize `RecyclerView` in fragment
Or add `RecyclerView`  tag in **activity_home.xml**